# Elasticsearch how to return the number of maching term for each document

Tags: elasticsearch, frequency

I'm very new to elasticsearch and I'm interested in how is possible to retrieve the number of matching term inside each document processed.
I know that I can get a score, but I'm looking to get number of matches for each document, is it possible?

**Edit after mguillermin answer**

What I was looking to is to query my index, and receive at the same time the tf on each document result, and not simply to find the term frequency of a single document

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For checking a single document, you can retrieve this kind of information using the `explain API` : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/explain/

If you need this information collected along with the query results, you can just add the `"explain": true` to the body sent to the `_search`. Ex :

```
{
    "explain": true,
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "description": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

With this parameter, you will get for each `hit` the associated `_explanation` data. Ex :

```
"_explanation": {
   "value": 1.4845161,
   "description": "fieldWeight(description:test in 63), product of:",
   "details": [
      {
         "value": 1,
         "description": "tf(termFreq(description:test)=1)"
      },
      {
         "value": 5.9380646,
         "description": "idf(docFreq=23, maxDocs=3348)"
      },
      {
         "value": 0.25,
         "description": "fieldNorm(field=description, doc=63)"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this works if I already have the document I want to query for. The problem is that I need to query for that term and in the result I need the term frequency for each document. In this case I need first to query for all the doc id that match the given term, and than for each doc I need to call explain to get the tf: this create too much overhead for each single search

Comment: You can also add the `explain` parameter to an existing query. That way, you don't need to do another query for each doc. I will add more information about this to my answer.